# Fill tensor with another tensor where mask is true

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I need to insert elements of tensor *new* into a tensor *old* with a certain probability, let's say that it is 0.8 for simplicity.
Substantially this is what masked_fill would do, but it only works with monodimensional tensor.
Actually I am doing

```
    prob = torch.rand(trgs.shape, dtype=torch.float32).to(trgs.device)
    mask = prob < 0.8

    dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4 = new.shape
    for a in range(dim1):
        for b in range(dim2):
            for c in range(dim3):
                for d in range(dim4):
                    old[a][b][c][d] = old[a][b][c][d] if mask[a][b][c][d] else new[a][b][c][d]
```

which is awful. I would like something like

```
    prob = torch.rand(trgs.shape, dtype=torch.float32).to(trgs.device)
    mask = prob < 0.8

    old = trgs.multidimensional_masked_fill(mask, new)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what some of your objects are, but this should get you to do what you need in short order:

`old` is the your existing data.

`mask` is the mask you generated with probability p

`new` is the new tensor that has elements you want to insert.

```
# torch.where
result = old.where(mask, new)
```